# How to ask / tell between Java-Akka and Pykka?

Tags: java, python, akka, pykka

I have a Java implementation of **Akka Actor** as shown below:

```
public class Rule1Actor extends UntypedActor{
   @Override 
   public void onReceive(Object message){
   ......
   }  
}
```

I need to call some `python script` within the `onReceive` method.  I wanted the python code to be an actor again. 
In that case, it would be implemented using `Pykka.`

**If so, how would I tell/ask between this Java-actor and Pykka-actor?**

Comment: Could you include some tag in your message to say what language you are using?

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot do that by using Akka remoting, there's no remoting in Pykka: https://github.com/jodal/pykka#what-pykka-is-not. Running a python script from java code (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447410/how-to-execute-python-script-from-java) would not be the same as tell/ask between actors.

Comment: Thats not what I meant. I meant in Akka, it's like a messaging system, no? and your message can be anything, so include some flag or identifer in the message to say "hey, I want python stuff for this message"

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry. I'm a beginner, a small example would be great help ! Thanks

Comment: @gmaslowski Basically one of my Actor needs to execute some DataAnalysis code implemented in Python. Currently this python code is not an Actor. If I made it to actor, then it seems that there is no ideal way to talk between actors written in different languages (Java - Python). Is it a good approach to run python script using Runtime etc within actor, performance wise? How far, the fault tolerance would be taken care for the python code?

Comment: @KavithaMadhavaraj it's not easy to answer that because it would depend on many aspects like performance, data volume, development costs and so on..

Comment: may be use some MQ(amqp etc.) in between?