# triggering a python script in a spring scheduled task

Tags: java, python, spring, cron

I have a python script needs to be run periodically. At first, I could consider triggering this script via a cronjob task. However, in my case, I have to do this through spring. The solution I am thinking of is writing a scheduled task in my spring app, and then running the python script via command line call. Is this possible in spring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible take a look at spring documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

You can enableScheduling with the

```
@EnableScheduling
```

Annotation. Then you have to add the

```
@Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * MON-FRI")
```

Annotation to your function. Just start a Process in there which executes the Python script for you. Here is another link where it is explained how to start a python script from java in the console:

[How to execute Python script from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447410/how-to-execute-python-script-from-java)

Hope that helps you.

Comment: thanks, I am trying to find the real path of the script located in resource path. resource/some.py. my application as a .jar file is deployed onto a tomcat server.

Comment: As a jar or as war?  Is it a spring boot app or is it a tomcat where you deploy the war/jar file? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340653/file-path-to-resource-in-our-war-web-inf-folder